# Bounds Error in Julia When Working with Arrays

Tags: arrays, julia, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to simulate a 3D random walk in Julia as a way to learn the ropes of Julia programming. I define all my variables and then initialize an (n_steps X 3) array of zeros that I want to use to store my coordinates when I do the walk. Here, "n_steps" is the number of steps in the walk, and the three columns correspond to the x, y, and z coordinates. When I try to update the array with my new coordinates, I get an error:

> ERROR: LoadError: BoundsError: attempt to access 100×3 Array{Float64,2} at index [0, 1]

I don't understand why I'm getting this error. As far as I know, I'm looping through all the rows of the array and updating the x, y, and z coordinates. I never mentioned the index 0, as I specified that the loop start at row number 1 in my code. What is going on? Here is my code so far (I haven't plotted yet, since I can't progress further without resolving this problem):

```
using Plots 
using Random

len_step = 1
θ_min, θ_max = 0, pi 
ϕ_min, ϕ_max = 0, 2 * pi

n_steps = 100

init = zeros(Float64, n_steps, 3)

for jj = 1:1:length(init)
    θ_rand = rand(Float64)* (θ_max - θ_min)
    ϕ_rand = rand(Float64)* (ϕ_max - ϕ_min)
    x_rand = len_step * sin(θ_rand) * cos(ϕ_rand)
    y_rand = len_step * sin(θ_rand) * sin(ϕ_rand)
    z_rand = len_step * cos(θ_rand)
    init[jj, 1] += init[jj-1, 1] + x_rand
    init[jj, 2] += init[jj-1, 2] + y_rand
    init[jj, 3] += init[jj-1, 3] + z_rand
end

print(init)
```

If it's relevant, I'm running Julia Version 1.4.2 on 64-Bit on Windows 10. I'd greatly appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to get any of the performance benefits of Julia, be sure you put your time-intensive code in functions. See https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/performance-tips/

Answer (score 2):

The function `length` returns the length of an array as if it was one dimensional. What you want is `size`

```
julia> init = zeros(3,5)
3×5 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0

julia> length(init)
15

julia> size(init)
(3, 5)

julia> size(init, 2)
5

julia> size(init, 1)
3
```

Note also that in julia, array indices start at 1, and since you access at index `jj-1`, you can not start the loop at `1`.

Comment: Also `jj` should start being indexed from `2` not `1` in the loop

Comment: Thanks, I added this to the answer!

Comment: Thanks! I changed the for loop line to "for jj = 2:1:n_steps" and now it works perfectly.